# Postgresql Contains in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause, contains

Is there a function in postgres like **`contains`** ? that can be used in the `where clause` to check , whether the string passed is contained in column?

Comment: You mean `LIKE '%abc%'` in SQL Server?

Comment: yes. I am aware of using like and ilike. But only static text can be passed to like/ ilike. i need to use something like col1 ilike %col2%. Where col1 and col2 are column values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways of solving this:

1. Use `like`, `ilike`, and/or `SIMILAR TO` along with ||.  To handle columns, something like:

   ```
   WHERE col1 ilike '%' || col2 || '%';
   ```
2. Use position as NPE's answer
3. You could also use `regexp_matches` but that is more complex.

Comment: It is possible to use `col1 ~ 'abc'` or `col1 ~ col2` also for this case.

Comment: I find that the performance of ~ is much better than LIKE (YMMV)

Comment: `~` is actually a REGEXP. The alias of like is `~~`

Answer (score 19):

You could use [`position()`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x8973_003.htm#AEN10365) for that. It returns zero if the substring is not found:

```
position(col2 in col1) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where TABLE_NAME like '%a%';
```

%a% > the results going to show you all the data that contains an a in any position of the value.

also, you can use:

```
%a > values where ending an a

a% > values starting with a

_a% > values with a in the second position
```